# Phone number validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have set up validation for a HTML form using jQuery and I'm looking for some help regarding the phone number validationy, I have been searching online and here's what I came up with but its still not working! I have the email and name inputs validating but cant figure out how to implement the phone number validation correctly as its still accepting letters when I submit? I need the input to only accept a maximum of 15 numbers and also accept the + sign at the start if neccessary?

The regEx I used is: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/ and I'm aware this isn't correct but I cant even get this to work?

Any input on how to fix this problem much appreciated!

```
$('#submit_second').click(function(){
    //remove classes
    $('#second_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
var phonePattern = /^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{7}$/ ;  
    var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]');
    var error = 0;
    fields.each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] || ( $(this).attr('id')=='email' && !emailPattern.test(value) )  ) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            error++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        }
    if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] || ( $(this).attr('id')=='phone' && !phonePattern.test(value) )  ) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            error++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        }


 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^\+?[0-9]{0,15}$/
```

This matches up to 15 numbers, optionally prefixed with `+`

Comment: Hi thanks for that! Im not sure if its just the regEx thats not working I think my code is wrong also? Is the code for the validation of the phone number incorrect? I dont recieve any error warnings for it but when I submit it to the server it still accepts letters as well as numbers without giving me the warning??

Comment: My code actually worked ok i just had a naming error with my submit button! Thanks :)